# Perform parallel calculations on tables and concatenate the results into one table

Tags: parallel-processing, dolphindb

I want to perform parallel calculations on several in-memory tables in DolphinDB and concatenate the results into one table.

For example, I want to create a UDF to perform calculations on a table *t0*, which involves a if-else statement:

- the condition is true: return *t0*
- the condition is false: return NULL values

At last, I wish to concatenate all the results into one table. Can anyone help me to write a script? Thanks in advance.

Here is a pseudocode for you:

```
def work(){
  t0=table(1 2 3 as a, `x`y`z as b, 10.8 7.6 3.5 as c);
  if(bad_cond){return NULL}
  else{return t0}
}
ploop(work)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following script:

```
def work(p){
  if(p==1) return table(1 2 3 as id)
  else return NULL
}

loop(work, 1 2 1).unionAll(false)
```

Here, `loop` returns a tuple containing the results of sub-jobs, and then the output tables are passed to `unionAll` to be concatenated.